# Discord.py Dont Rename Voice Channel

Tags: python, discord.py

For some Reason My Bot can't rename a Voice Channel. I try to rename my Bot with the following, but its awaiting forever

```
await vc.edit(name = "Test")
```

It does Work like 2 or 3 Times, but when I try to rename the Voice Channel for the 4th time, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I Just found out that you only allowed to rename a Voice Channel twice every 10 Minutes due to the Discord Rate limit